# Removing un-supported chars from string

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a json string returned from a server with a list of songs, but the encoding it uses is different to that of WP7 (I think).

When I load the string into a textblock on the device is has the typical windows empty white square, but in VS in the element inspector it isn't shown, nor is it in the json file when I open it in sublime (there should be a char between the n and t in "cant"):

[image: Sublime 3 Text]

But when I open it in a hex editor I see this:

[image]

So my question is how can I fix this, without making a blacklist of unsupported bytes and replaceing them every-time I grab the json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone indeed only supports UTF-8 and UTF-16.

However, there is a [Text Encoding Class Generator](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) out there that will generate code for you to handle the specific encoding that your scenario requires. This may save you a lot of time.